# Take into account records not in timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are querying a RFID database, and counting the amount of reads on s specific hourly timeframe. But when there are no records, the timeframe is not shown, as it should. However, we want to actually report that on that timeframe there are no records.

This is the query:

```
select
date_tr,
right('0000'+ convert(varchar,timeofday),2) + '00 - ' + right('0000'+ convert(varchar,timeofday+1),2) + '00' as timeofday,
count(placa) reads
from
(select distinct gi.placa,
convert(varchar(10), tr.inDate,101) as date_tr,
datepart(hour, tr.inDate) timeofday
from
RFIDTransaction tr, RFIDGeneralInformation gi
where
gi.tag = tr.tag 
and inDate between current_timestamp - 1 and current_timestamp
and inLoc = 'GATE IN'
and gi.removed = 0
and tr.removed = 0
group by convert(varchar(10), tr.inDate,101), datepart(hour, tr.inDate), gi.placa) xx
group by date_tr, timeofday
order by date_tr, timeofday
```

The output of this query is something like this:

```
date_tr     timeofday      reads
01/19/2014  0500 - 0600    12
01/19/2014  0600 - 0700    15
01/19/2014  0800 - 0900    22
...
```

NOW, We need to show the timeframe 0700 - 0800 with ZERO reads.

How can I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: As a point in the right direction, I tend to use a base table that would provide a list of applicable date/time ranges and use that as the main table and then left outer join it to the results that may not exist. That said, please use the explicit join syntax unless you have a solid reason not to. It will make future support easier for you or your replacement

Answer (score 3):

Here is a 2005-friendly solution.

```
;WITH t AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT gi.placa, -- not sure that you really want distinct there
     d = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,tr.inDate),0), h = DATEPART(HOUR, tr.inDate)
  FROM dbo.RFIDTransaction AS tr
  INNER JOIN dbo.RFIDGeneralInformation AS gi
  ON tr.tag = gi.tag
  WHERE tr.inDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    AND tr.inDate <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    AND tr.removed = 0 AND gi.removed = 0
    AND tr.inLoc = 'GATE IN'
),
h(h) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (24) DATEADD(HOUR,-number,DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,GETDATE()),0))
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE [type] = N'P' AND number > 0 
    ORDER BY number
),
s AS 
(
  SELECT 
    dh = h.h, 
    d = CONVERT(CHAR(10), h.h, 101), 
    hs = CONVERT(CHAR(2), h.h, 108), 
    he = CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATEADD(HOUR, 1, h.h), 108),
    c = COUNT(t.d) 
  FROM h LEFT OUTER JOIN t
  ON DATEADD(HOUR, t.h, t.d) >= h.h
  AND DATEADD(HOUR, t.h, t.d) < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, h.h)
  GROUP BY h.h
)
SELECT 
  date_tr = d, 
  timeofday = RIGHT('0' + hs,2) + '00 - ' + RIGHT('0' + he,2) + '00',
  reads = c
FROM s ORDER BY dh;
```

Various problems implicitly addressed (click for more info):

- [Don't convert to types like `VARCHAR` without explicitly declaring length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)
- [Don't convert to `VARCHAR` to strip time](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime) and [part two](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time)
- [Don't use `BETWEEN` for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

For posterity, original post below:

---

You need to create a set of all of the possible timeframes first, then outer join. The general technique is as follows (you can work out how to incorporate that into your existing code, which is far beyond the scope of the actual problem IMHO).

In SQL Server 2008, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(d DATETIME);

INSERT @d SELECT '05:03' UNION ALL SELECT '05:07' UNION ALL SELECT '07:05';

;WITH x(s,e,i) AS 
(
  SELECT 
    s = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, number, 0)), 
    e = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, number+1, 0)),
    i = RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(number),2)   + '00 - '
      + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(number+1),2) + '00' 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (24) number
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
    WHERE [type] = N'P' 
    ORDER BY number
  )
  AS x
)
SELECT x.i, COUNT(d.d) FROM x
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @d AS d
  ON CONVERT(TIME, d.d) >= x.s
  AND CONVERT(TIME, d.d) < x.e
  -- AND date is the date you're looking for
  GROUP BY x.i;
```

Little more work to do in 2005, since you can't take advantage of `TIME`. I'll have to revisit this when I have more time, just wanted to express the basic approach to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create another table pre-filled with all 24 time periods, and do a join with it:

```
Interval_ID Interval
    1       0000-0100
    2       0100-0200
...
```

Do an outer join, and any interval with no data will show up with nulls in the 'reads'.  Convert them to zeros if you want.

It's a reasonably common technique to do this for dates, and there's no reason it couldn't be done with intervals.  Some times, it's even convenient to have a table that contains nothing but a list of all integers from 1 to 1000, just for solving this sort of counting problem.

-update-

If you can't create a table to join to, you can try joining to a set created in the query.  The syntax would be something like this:

```
select
  intervals.interval,
  mytable.*
from
  mytable
right join (
  select '0000-0100' as interval
  union all
  select '0100-0200' as interval
  union all
  ...
  select '2300-2400' as interval ) intervals
on
  mytable.interval = intervals.interval
```

That's code off the top of my head, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.  Not elegant, but since you're only concerned with 24 values, it's not too bad.

Comment: That was my first thought, however, I'm not allowed to create new tables on this database. Is there a way of creating the table on the fly? Like select and union statements with the raw data?

Comment: Can you create temporary tables?

Comment: That worked perfectly.

But I have another issue. My date selection is 24 hours behind, so I'm getting the past 48 hours worth of hour ranges, but there is only data for the last 24. The previous hours, from today - 24hrs and from this moment to the end of the day, are null. So it shows as if there were no reads on those ranges. Let me know if you know what I mean, or I should post the current query and results. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1753599: Do you think that would still be the same question as you asked originally or a different one? You might want to post that as a new question to avoid turning this one into a mess.

Comment: No need to. I found a fix to it. I simply added a date field to the temporary table, and upon joining it with the main table, I used that field to select just the records for the corresponding time frame.

Thanks to all for the help. Appreciate it.